# Countdown control with arc animation

Tags: c#, animation, wpf, timer

I've implemented countdown timer control with arc animation that looks like this

[image: countdown control]

---

Implementation notes:

- For arc visualization I've created class `Arc` derived from `Shape` (code is based on this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16669648/1548895)).
- I've created `Countdown` control (derived from `UserControl`). For setting timeout I've added `Seconds` dependency property. I'm using binding `Content="{Binding Seconds}"` to display seconds. Animation duration is set in code behind

  ```
  Animation.Duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(Seconds));
  ```

  because I'm not sure if it's possible to do it in XAML without writing custom converter. I think that creating custom converter is not justified here.
- For control's scaling content is wrapped in `Viewbox` сontrol.
- For seconds animation I'm using `DispatcherTimer`, nothing special. Is it the best to go here?

---

### Code

`Arc.cs`

```
public class Arc : Shape
{
    public Point Center
    {
        get => (Point)GetValue(CenterProperty);
        set => SetValue(CenterProperty, value);
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for Center.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty CenterProperty = 
        DependencyProperty.Register("Center", typeof(Point), typeof(Arc), 
            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(new Point(), FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsRender));

    // Start angle in degrees
    public double StartAngle
    {
        get => (double)GetValue(StartAngleProperty);
        set => SetValue(StartAngleProperty, value);
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for StartAngle.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty StartAngleProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("StartAngle", typeof(double), typeof(Arc),
            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(0.0, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsRender));

    // End angle in degrees
    public double EndAngle
    {
        get => (double)GetValue(EndAngleProperty);
        set => SetValue(EndAngleProperty, value);
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for EndAngle.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty EndAngleProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("EndAngle", typeof(double), typeof(Arc),
            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(90.0, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsRender));

    public double Radius
    {
        get => (double)GetValue(RadiusProperty);
        set => SetValue(RadiusProperty, value);
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for Radius.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty RadiusProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Radius", typeof(double), typeof(Arc),
            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(10.0, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsRender));

    public bool SmallAngle
    {
        get => (bool)GetValue(SmallAngleProperty);
        set => SetValue(SmallAngleProperty, value);
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for SmallAngle.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty SmallAngleProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("SmallAngle", typeof(bool), typeof(Arc),
            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(false, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsRender));

    static Arc() => DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(Arc), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(Arc)));

    protected override Geometry DefiningGeometry
    {
        get
        {
            double startAngleRadians = StartAngle * Math.PI / 180;
            double endAngleRadians = EndAngle * Math.PI / 180;

            double a0 = StartAngle < 0 ? startAngleRadians + 2 * Math.PI : startAngleRadians;
            double a1 = EndAngle < 0 ? endAngleRadians + 2 * Math.PI : endAngleRadians;

            if (a1 < a0)
                a1 += Math.PI * 2;

            SweepDirection d = SweepDirection.Counterclockwise;
            bool large;

            if (SmallAngle)
            {
                large = false;
                double t = a1;
                d = (a1 - a0) > Math.PI ? SweepDirection.Counterclockwise : SweepDirection.Clockwise;
            }
            else
                large = (Math.Abs(a1 - a0) < Math.PI);

            Point p0 = Center + new Vector(Math.Cos(a0), Math.Sin(a0)) * Radius;
            Point p1 = Center + new Vector(Math.Cos(a1), Math.Sin(a1)) * Radius;

            List<PathSegment> segments = new List<PathSegment>
            {
                new ArcSegment(p1, new Size(Radius, Radius), 0.0, large, d, true)
            };

            List<PathFigure> figures = new List<PathFigure>
            {
                new PathFigure(p0, segments, true)
                {
                    IsClosed = false
                }
            };

            return new PathGeometry(figures, FillRule.EvenOdd, null);
        }
    }
}
```

`Countdown.xaml`

```
<UserControl x:Class="WpfApp3.Countdown"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp"
             mc:Ignorable="d"
             d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="450" Loaded="UserControl_Loaded">
    <UserControl.Triggers>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="UserControl.Loaded">
            <BeginStoryboard>
                <Storyboard>
                    <DoubleAnimation Name="Animation"
                        Storyboard.TargetName="Arc"
                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="EndAngle"
                        From="-90"
                        To="270" />
                </Storyboard>
            </BeginStoryboard>
        </EventTrigger>
    </UserControl.Triggers>
    <Viewbox>
        <Grid Width="100" Height="100">
            <Border Background="#222" Margin="5" CornerRadius="50">
                <StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                    <Label Foreground="#fff" Content="{Binding Seconds}" FontSize="50" Margin="0, -10, 0, 0" />
                    <Label Foreground="#fff" Content="sec" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0, -20, 0, 0" />
                </StackPanel>
            </Border>

            <local:Arc
                x:Name="Arc"
                Center="50, 50"
                StartAngle="-90"
                EndAngle="-90"
                Stroke="#45d3be"
                StrokeThickness="5"
                Radius="45" />
        </Grid>
    </Viewbox>
</UserControl>
```

`Countdown.xaml.cs`

```
public partial class Countdown : UserControl
{
    public int Seconds
    {
        get => (int)GetValue(SecondsProperty);
        set => SetValue(SecondsProperty, value);
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty SecondsProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(Seconds), typeof(int), typeof(Countdown), new PropertyMetadata(0));

    private readonly DispatcherTimer _timer = new DispatcherTimer { Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1) };

    public Countdown()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = this;
    }

    private void UserControl_Loaded(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Animation.Duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(Seconds));
        if (Seconds > 0)
        {
            _timer.Start();
            _timer.Tick += Timer_Tick;
        }
    }

    private void Timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Seconds--;
        if (Seconds == 0) _timer.Stop();
    }
}
```

Control is placed on `Window` like this

```
<local:Countdown Width="300" Height="300" Seconds="25" />
```

Comment: Are you sure this actually works? It counts for a single second and stops when I have tried to use it?

Comment: @David Take a look at my self-answer that was used in my app https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/197234/119568 afterwards but it should work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't like that you are running two timers/timelines in parallel. Instead you could run the animation from code behind. It also gives you the opportunity to trigger it from other places than load:

```
private void StartAnimation()
{
  double from = -90;
  double to = 270;
  int seconds = Seconds;
  TimeSpan duration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(Seconds);

  DoubleAnimation animation = new DoubleAnimation(from, to, new Duration(duration));

  Storyboard.SetTarget(animation, Arc);
  Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(animation, new PropertyPath("EndAngle"));

  Storyboard storyboard = new Storyboard();
  storyboard.CurrentTimeInvalidated += (s, e) =>
  {
    int diff = (int)((s as ClockGroup).CurrentTime.Value.TotalSeconds); 
    Seconds = seconds - diff;
  };

  storyboard.Children.Add(animation);
  storyboard.Begin();
}

private void UserControl_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  StartAnimation();
  //Animation.Duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(Seconds));
  //if (Seconds > 0)
  //{
  //  _timer.Tick += Timer_Tick;
  //  _timer.Start();
  //}
}
```

---

```
<UserControl x:Class="WpfApp3.Countdown"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800"
             Loaded="UserControl_Loaded"
             >
  <Viewbox>
    <Grid Width="100" Height="100">
      <Border Background="#222" Margin="5" CornerRadius="50">
        <StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
          <Label Foreground="#fff" Content="{Binding Seconds}" FontSize="50" Margin="0, -10, 0, 0" />
          <Label Foreground="#fff" Content="sec" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0, -20, 0, 0" />
        </StackPanel>
      </Border>

      <local:Arc
                x:Name="Arc"
                Center="50, 50"
                StartAngle="-90"
                EndAngle="-90"
                Stroke="#45d3be"
                StrokeThickness="5"
                Radius="45" />
    </Grid>
  </Viewbox>
</UserControl>
```

Answer (score 10):

There are a couple of things which could be more consistent.

> ```
>     public static readonly DependencyProperty StartAngleProperty =
>         DependencyProperty.Register("StartAngle", typeof(double), typeof(Arc),
>             new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(0.0, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsRender));
> ```

> ```
>     public static readonly DependencyProperty SecondsProperty =
>         DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(Seconds), typeof(int), typeof(Countdown), new PropertyMetadata(0));
> ```

The dependency property in `Countdown.xaml.cs` uses `nameof`, but the ones in `Arc.cs` don't. IMO they should.

---

> ```
>     // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for SmallAngle.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
>     public static readonly DependencyProperty SmallAngleProperty =
>         DependencyProperty.Register("SmallAngle", typeof(bool), typeof(Arc),
>             new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(false, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsRender));
>
>     static Arc() => DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(Arc), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(Arc)));
> ```

The dependency properties in `Arc.cs` all have a comment, but the constructor doesn't. IMO the constructor is the harder of the two to understand: if someone knows enough WPF to understand that without a comment, they don't need the comments on the dependency properties.

---

> ```
>             double startAngleRadians = StartAngle * Math.PI / 180;
>             double endAngleRadians = EndAngle * Math.PI / 180;
>
>             double a0 = StartAngle < 0 ? startAngleRadians + 2 * Math.PI : startAngleRadians;
>             double a1 = EndAngle < 0 ? endAngleRadians + 2 * Math.PI : endAngleRadians;
>
>             if (a1 < a0)
>                 a1 += Math.PI * 2;
>
>             SweepDirection d = SweepDirection.Counterclockwise;
>             bool large;
>
>             if (SmallAngle)
>             {
>                 large = false;
>                 double t = a1;
>                 d = (a1 - a0) > Math.PI ? SweepDirection.Counterclockwise : SweepDirection.Clockwise;
>             }
>             else
>                 large = (Math.Abs(a1 - a0) < Math.PI);
> ```

I could definitely use some comments to explain what's going on here. The last line in particular looks very counterintuitive.

Also there's a dead line: `t` isn't used anywhere.

---

> ```
>                     <Label Foreground="#fff" Content="{Binding Seconds}" FontSize="50" Margin="0, -10, 0, 0" />
>                     <Label Foreground="#fff" Content="sec" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0, -20, 0, 0" />
> ```

Not very localisable...

---

> ```
>             _timer.Start();
>             _timer.Tick += Timer_Tick;
> ```

It's unlikely to occur in practice, but *technically* you've got a race condition there. I see only an advantage in switching the order of the two lines.

---

> ... For setting timeout I've added Seconds dependency property. I'm using binding `Content="{Binding Seconds}"` to display seconds. Animation duration is
>   set in code behind
>
> ```
> Animation.Duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(Seconds));
> ```
>
> because I'm not sure if it's possible to do it in XAML without writing
>   custom converter. I think that creating custom converter is not
>   justified here.

I *think* you can do it without a custom converter by making the binding property a `TimeSpan` (changing the name from `Seconds` to something like `TimeRemaining`) and using `StringFormat` in the binding for the label content. I haven't tested this.

If you do this then you might want to handle non-integer `TimeSpan.TotalSeconds` values by rounding to the nearest second in the setter.

Comment: Regarding "Not very localisable…" if I would need localization I'll just add something like `Content="{x:Static p:Resources.Sec}"`. I'm using Resx-files based localization, don't know if it's the best option, but didn't find good alternatives, what do you think? But I assume adding this piece of code to the question would be redundant.

Comment: I haven't found any good standard l10n approach for WPF. I ended up doing a DIY approach with a custom converter and various ugly hacks. If you've thought about the issue and made a decision that YAGNI then that's fair enough.

Answer (score 7):

1) `DispatcherTimer` is good for periodic UI updates, but it should not be used to measure time, because it is just not accurate enough. For precise time measurement you have to use `Stopwatch` class inside the timer callback.

2) `Seconds` property apparently does two things: it starts as "countdown duration" but after control is loaded it acts as "remaining time". I would use two properties here, so that they can be databound separately when necessary.

3) `DataContext = this;` - don't set `DataContext` on public re-usable types. Someone (yourself included) can eventually decide to use this class in MVVM environment, but changing `DataContext` of your class will break it. Internally, you should use `RelativeSource` or `ElementName` properties of `Binding` class or `DependencyProperty` callbacks to do your bidding, while leaving `DataContext` empty.

Here is an example of using `ElementName`:

```
<UserControl x:Class="WpfApp3.Countdown"
         ...
         x:Name="this">

 ...
         <!-- Content binds directly to Countdown.Seconds dependency property, DataContext is ignored -->
         <Label Content="{Binding Seconds, ElementName=this}" />
 ...
 </UserControl>
```

Comment: Regarding last point: suppose I want to move my properties from control class to some view model class. When I have `DataContext` assigned I just need to change `DataContext` stored reference, but when I don't have one I need to rewrite all my bindings. So I'm not sure if using `DataContext` is bad idea here. Am I missing something?

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov, I'm not sure I follow. Why do you want to move the properties? Just leave them where they are. For MVVM to work, you need to have a property on each side: one property on your view, and another property on your viewmodel. Then you can bind them by setting viewmodel as datacontext: `<Countdown Duration={Binding DurationPropertyOfViewModel} DataContext={Binding ViewModel}/>`

Answer (score 3):

Incorporated nearly all recommendations to my solution, but the most radical was [accepted answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/197212/119568). Any feedback very welcome!

Also added public `Start` and `Stop` methods and `Elapsed` event.

Results:

`Arc.cs`

```
public class Arc : Shape
{
    public Point Center
    {
        get => (Point)GetValue(CenterProperty);
        set => SetValue(CenterProperty, value);
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty CenterProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(Center), typeof(Point), typeof(Arc),
            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(new Point(), FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsRender));

    public double StartAngle
    {
        get => (double)GetValue(StartAngleProperty);
        set => SetValue(StartAngleProperty, value);
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty StartAngleProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(StartAngle), typeof(double), typeof(Arc),
            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(0.0, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsRender));

    public double EndAngle
    {
        get => (double)GetValue(EndAngleProperty);
        set => SetValue(EndAngleProperty, value);
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty EndAngleProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(EndAngle), typeof(double), typeof(Arc),
            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(90.0, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsRender));

    public double Radius
    {
        get => (double)GetValue(RadiusProperty);
        set => SetValue(RadiusProperty, value);
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty RadiusProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(Radius), typeof(double), typeof(Arc),
            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(10.0, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsRender));

    public bool SmallAngle
    {
        get => (bool)GetValue(SmallAngleProperty);
        set => SetValue(SmallAngleProperty, value);
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty SmallAngleProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(SmallAngle), typeof(bool), typeof(Arc),
            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(false, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsRender));

    static Arc() => DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(Arc), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(Arc)));

    protected override Geometry DefiningGeometry
    {
        get
        {
            double startAngleRadians = StartAngle * Math.PI / 180;
            double endAngleRadians = EndAngle * Math.PI / 180;

            double a0 = StartAngle < 0 ? startAngleRadians + 2 * Math.PI : startAngleRadians;
            double a1 = EndAngle < 0 ? endAngleRadians + 2 * Math.PI : endAngleRadians;

            if (a1 < a0)
                a1 += Math.PI * 2;

            SweepDirection d = SweepDirection.Counterclockwise;
            bool large;

            if (SmallAngle)
            {
                large = false;
                d = (a1 - a0) > Math.PI ? SweepDirection.Counterclockwise : SweepDirection.Clockwise;
            }
            else
                large = (Math.Abs(a1 - a0) < Math.PI);

            Point p0 = Center + new Vector(Math.Cos(a0), Math.Sin(a0)) * Radius;
            Point p1 = Center + new Vector(Math.Cos(a1), Math.Sin(a1)) * Radius;

            List<PathSegment> segments = new List<PathSegment>
            {
                new ArcSegment(p1, new Size(Radius, Radius), 0.0, large, d, true)
            };

            List<PathFigure> figures = new List<PathFigure>
            {
                new PathFigure(p0, segments, true)
                {
                    IsClosed = false
                }
            };

            return new PathGeometry(figures, FillRule.EvenOdd, null);
        }
    }
}
```

`Countdown.xaml`

```
<UserControl x:Class="WpfApp.Countdown"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="450" Loaded="Countdown_Loaded">
    <Viewbox>
        <Grid Width="100" Height="100">
            <Border Background="#222" Margin="5" CornerRadius="50">
                <StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                    <Label Foreground="#fff" Content="{Binding SecondsRemaining}" FontSize="50" Margin="0, -10, 0, 0" />
                    <Label Foreground="#fff" Content="sec" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0, -15, 0, 0" />
                </StackPanel>
            </Border>

            <uc:Arc
                x:Name="Arc"
                Center="50, 50"
                StartAngle="-90"
                EndAngle="-90"
                Stroke="#45d3be"
                StrokeThickness="5"
                Radius="45" />
        </Grid>
    </Viewbox>
</UserControl>
```

`Countdown.xaml.cs`

```
public partial class Countdown : UserControl
{
    public Duration Duration
    {
        get => (Duration)GetValue(DurationProperty);
        set => SetValue(DurationProperty, value);
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty DurationProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(Duration), typeof(Duration), typeof(Countdown), new PropertyMetadata(new Duration()));

    public int SecondsRemaining
    {
        get => (int)GetValue(SecondsRemainingProperty);
        set => SetValue(SecondsRemainingProperty, value);
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty SecondsRemainingProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(SecondsRemaining), typeof(int), typeof(Countdown), new PropertyMetadata(0));

    public event EventHandler Elapsed;

    private readonly Storyboard _storyboard = new Storyboard();

    public Countdown()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        DoubleAnimation animation = new DoubleAnimation(-90, 270, Duration);
        Storyboard.SetTarget(animation, Arc);
        Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(animation, new PropertyPath(nameof(Arc.EndAngle)));
        _storyboard.Children.Add(animation);

        DataContext = this;
    }

    private void Countdown_Loaded(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (IsVisible)
            Start();
    }

    public void Start()
    {
        Stop();

        _storyboard.CurrentTimeInvalidated += Storyboard_CurrentTimeInvalidated;
        _storyboard.Completed += Storyboard_Completed;

        _storyboard.Begin();
    }

    public void Stop()
    {
        _storyboard.CurrentTimeInvalidated -= Storyboard_CurrentTimeInvalidated;
        _storyboard.Completed -= Storyboard_Completed;

        _storyboard.Stop();
    }

    private void Storyboard_CurrentTimeInvalidated(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ClockGroup cg = (ClockGroup)sender;
        if (cg.CurrentTime == null) return;
        TimeSpan elapsedTime = cg.CurrentTime.Value;
        SecondsRemaining = (int)Math.Ceiling((Duration.TimeSpan - elapsedTime).TotalSeconds);
    }

    private void Storyboard_Completed(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (IsVisible)
            Elapsed?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    }
}
```

Example of usage:

```
<local:Countdown Width="300" Height="300" Duration="0:0:15" />
```